# Github: How can I require PRs to be approved by me, unless they are my own?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a private Github repo which I want to make public, but:

1. I don't want people to be able to merge their PRs without my approval
2. I want to be able to merge my own PRs without anyone's approval

Is this possible and how ?

I couldn't find a combination of the above while looking at my repo's settings, unless I pay for a PRO account.

Comment: You could allow forking, and people other than you would have read access, and create their PRs from forks?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exact answer, but it should be similar for public repo. I have a private repo and paid account with one additional user license, so I can review and require approval of other user's PRs.

This is how I setup protection. repo -> Settings -> Branches (under code and automation) -> Branch protection rule -> enter a branch pattern (like release*) ..there are number of checkboxes and you want to pick whatever protection you need.

For eg. I picked:

- Require a pull request before merging
  -- Require approvals

However, found an interesting option which might be useful to you. So if you are administrator you should be able to bypass the protection but other non-admins cannot is what I am gathering

```
Do not allow bypassing the above settings
The above settings will apply to administrators and custom roles with the "bypass branch protections" permission.
```